# По поводу буквы Ы

Tags: фонетика

Послушал новый этюд Жириновского по поводу "гадкой" буквы Ы. А действительно, она вообще была в русском языке изначально, или, как он говорит, пришла к нам из тюркского? Есть ли хоть доля смысла в том, что говорил Жириновский?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Никакого смысла в том, что говорит Жириновской, нет и не было.
Прежде всего: он перепутал звук и букву.
Звук еще может (при каких-то весьма экзотических обстоятельствах) быть "позаимствованным" из другого языка, буква сознаётся вместе с алфавитом (или дополняется позднее) - и её история известна. В тюркских такой **буквы** нет и быть не может. Звук есть, но вряд ли он мог "проникнуть" в славянские.

Далее. Славянский алфавит (кириллица) был создан на основе греческого по фонетическому принципу - недостающие буквы были созданы для звуков, не имеющих прямых аналогов в греческом, среди них и была буква Ы. Ранее она писалась как ЪI (обычно - с горизонтальной черточкой между частями), называлась ЕРЫ (от ЕРЪ + И) и воспринималась как диграф: "непалатизующее И", т.е. "И, которое не смягчает предыдущую согласную". 
Аналогичное начертание имел "ЕРЫ" в другой славянской азбуке - глаголице.

Что касается наличия подобного звука в славянских, то он есть (с очень небольшими вариациями) в украинском и белорусском, т.е. во всех восточнославянских. В других славянских он безусловно существовал, поскольку был в едином алфавите, для всех славян создаваемом, но затем - частично утратился, частично стал кодироваться на письме другими графемами.

Я сознательно опустил некоторые моменты, связанные с понятием звука и фонемы (Ы и И), поскольку это вопрос до сих пор является предметом спора фонологических школ. На суть ответа, надеюсь, это не повлияло.

Подробнее
http://gramota.ru/lenta/news/8_2893

Comment: >В других славянских он безусловно существовал, поскольку был в едином алфавите, для всех славян создаваемом, но затем - частично утратился, частично стал кодироваться на письме другими графемами. 

Да. Например, у сербов и хорватов звук "Ы" раньше был. А потом вышел из употребления и теперь на его месте "И".

Comment: Есть версия о том, что предки хорватов пришли на Балканы с территории нынешней Украины. В *некоторых* говорах на Украине и теперь звук "Ы" произносится мягко, только незначительно отличаясь от "И". Так что, если предположить, что носители подобного говора пожили изолированно несколько столетий, то вполне возможно, что такая разница между "Ы" и "И" могла бы совсем исчезнуть.

.

Но главное, если говорить по теме вопроса, буква "Ы" "была в русском языке изначально". И у древних славян.

Answer (score 0):

По моему мнению, в современном русском алфавите есть по меньшей мере две аномальные буквы.

Аномальная буква "ё" введена в русский язык Е.Р. Дашковой, а аномальная буква "ы" образовалась из разделительного знака "ъ" и буквы "i" после того, как в древнерусском языке стал использоваться разделительный знак " " (пробел).

Буква "ы" (в русском языке) и буква "и" (в украинском языке) передают один и тот же звук [ы]. Например, русское слово "жиды" и украинское слово "жиди" произносятся одинаково, а именно [жыды].

Comment: @Галактион настолько заострён на русском варианте жизни общества, что даже в примере он не мог обойти без внимания слово "жид". Похвальная "настойчивость", но, по крайней мере, тематически не оправданная

Comment: Что такое "заострённость на русском варианте жизни общества"?

Comment: Не хочется называть вещи своими именами. Не будем?

Comment: Кому "не хочется называть вещи своими именами"?

Comment: Никому. В том числе и Вам.

Comment: Принял к сведению, что, по Вашему мнению, мне "не хочется называть вещи своими именами". Что ещё?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего был этот звук но писалась другая буква,например вот это южное или Украинское ГЭканье в диалектах Русского языка присудствует, но в письме его нет.Уверен что и у предков тоже были диалекты но многие звуки не фиксировались.